# Variable use and interpolation inside Rails localization file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization, yaml

Is either of these possible (and if so how):

1.)
Use a previously defined entry in the localization file, in another place in the localization file

```
en:
  account:
    label: "MegaCorp"
  user:
    creation: "Welcome aboard user of {{en.account.label}}"

 # => Welcome aboard user of MegaCorp
```

2.)
Use a globally available method.

```
class Account
  def self.to_s
    "MegaCorp"
  end
end
```

and yml

```
en:
  user:
    creation: "Welcome aboard user of {{Account.to_s}}"

 # => Welcome aboard user of MegaCorp
```

Or any other variable interpolation possibilities inside localization files. I know the standard format.

```
<%=t 'user.creation', account_name: "MegaCorp" %>

en:
  user:
    creation: "Welcome aboard user of %{account_name}"
```

But i need more than that and I wonder if there are any other undocumented tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly I'm probably stretching the scope of the question too far but ... what about using `.rb` files for the translations? You can do both of your points then.

1) Instead of `config/locales/en.yml` (say), you can have `config/locales/en.rb`:

```
account_name = 'Megacorp'

{
  en: {
    account: {
      label: account_name
    },
    user: {
      creation: 'Welcome aboard user of ' + account_name
    }
  }
}
```

2) Similarly you can use a class variable in `en.rb`:

```
{
  en: {
    user: {
      creation: 'Welcome aboard user of ' + Account.to_s
    }
  }
}
```

You don't have to use `.rb` files for all your translations if you prefer yaml (and most people do) but you could use it for those translations that you want to do this kind of thing on.

Comment: I haven't tried the ruby file method. Could be interesting.

Comment: This is the way to go about it. When using YAML serialization all the values will be strings and the i18n gem will simply apply gsub + sprintf on it. https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb 

When using Ruby, you can also put lambdas as your values and the interpolator will execute them with the parameters. It gives you all the flexibility in the world.

Another approach is to write your own custom backend translator methods. This is a non-trivial exercise http://blog.lingohub.com/developers/2013/08/i18n-gem-advanced-features-ruby-rails-internationalization/